# Cant get cart items for order using laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a cart app using laravel. I am trying to get orders data with cart items nested inside the order object. I have order data in orders table and cart data in cart table. When I try to fetch order for a particular user I get the order data from orders table but get empty array for cart items.

```
public function getUserOrders($id) {
    $orders = Order::with('cart')->where('userId', $id)->get();
    return response()->json($orders, 200);
}
```

Following are order and cart models respectively

```
class Order extends Model {
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function cart() {
        return $this->hasMany(Cart::class, 'cartId', 'id');
    }
}

class Cart extends Model {
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function order() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class, 'cartId', 'id');
    }

}
```

Data Screenshots

[image: Orders Table]

[image: Cart Table]

As can be seen in dataset screenshots the matching cartId exists in both tables it should return order number 7112 with corresponding items with same number from cart table but it only returns data from orders table and cart is returned as empty array. Any idea what could be wrong.

Comment: I can see their is a mismatch between order and cart items.  you are passing same id for cart and order ,due to that you are not getting cart data. pls check the passing id's properly by using echo and break statements in between to debug it.

Comment: Maybe you define their relationship wrong. Does `order` belongs to `cart` or `cart` belongs to `order` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure and Eloquent relations are wrong.

- You should not have a *CartId* field in the **Orders** table.
- You should have a **order_id** field in the **Carts** table

And rewrite the models as below

```
class Order extends Model {
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function cart() {
        return $this->hasMany(Cart::class);
    }
}

class Cart extends Model {
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function order() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
}
```

Or if you are not following Laravel default naming convention, you can use **OrderId** field and rewrite the Model as following

```
class Order extends Model {
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function cart() {
        return $this->hasMany(Cart::class, 'OrderId', 'id');
    }
}

class Cart extends Model {
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function order() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class, 'OrderId', 'id');
    }
}
```

If you intent to use a separate primary key other than `id` column then define a protected `$primaryKey` property on your model

```
protected $primaryKey = 'cartId';
```

otherwise Laravel will take the default `id` field as primary key and your relationships will not work.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: cartId basically works as order Id because every order is identified by cartId and I have that field in both tables so relationship is there. Sure I can rename it as OrderId as you suggested but it wont make any difference. Do I need to set cartId as primary key in orders table?

Comment: If you are using a separate primary key other than 'id' you should specify it in your model file using protected $primaryKey = 'cartId'; otherwise Laravel will take the default id field as primary key and your relationships will not work.